# Proof that $\phi'(0)$ exists but expectation doesn't converges.

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Consider $X = (-1)^{k}k$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = (-1)^{k}k) = \frac{const}{k^{2}\log{k}}$ for $k \ge 2$. Then let's find $\mathbb{E}|X| = \sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{k}{k^{2} \log{k}} = \infty$, so expectation doesn't converges.

Let's consider characteristic function of $X$ : $\phi(t) = \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{e^{ikt}}{k^{2}\log{k}}$. So we have that our series is uniformly converges and function under sum sign is continuous , so we can find first derivate at zero. But when I differentiate it , I have that $\phi'(0)$ diverges. Where is my problem ? Does it have connection with complex part of function?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the contradiction? If $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly and each $f_n$ is differentiable it is not necessary that $\sum f'_n$ converges. Which theorem is being contradicted?

Comment: I understand but first derivate of characteristic function at zero should exists.

Comment: Can you tell me why it should exist?

Comment: this is a task. We need to prove that $\phi'(0)$ exists , but $\mathbb{E} |X|$ diverges for this random variable

Comment: The standard example is $X=k$ or $-k$ with probability $\frac C {k^{2} \ln k}$. This means $X$ takes all integer values and your definition is different. I know the proof for the standard example but in your case differentiability looks a bit doubtful Are you sure you have copied the problem correctly?

Comment: in my problem $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$